# Retention policy and recurrence

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, information-management

I'd like to set up a retention policy in a document library so that the editor of a document recieves an e-mail when the document was not modified within the last year. Then the editor of the document should recieve an e-mail every 7 days as a reminder so that he/she is "forced" to update the document or delete it, if it's outdated.

I've configured a policy like this:
  Event: Modified + 12 months
  Action: Start a workflow (sends an e-mail to the last editor)
  Recurrence: Every 7 days

The timer jobs for the retention are configured like this:
  Information management policy: weekly; friday 11pm
  Expiration policy: weekly; saturday 11pm

I've received e-mails for the "initial" event (modified + 12 months), but I do not receive the weekly "follow up" e-mails.

Any ideas why recurrence / series is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're using the action "Start a workflow" the workflow is linked to the policy.

During the testing period I had to make changes to the workflow and published a new version of the workflow to the document library. **But the policy was still linked to the initial version of the workflow** (which had an error so that no e-mails had been sent).

In my case I've even deleted the old version of the workflow (resulting in the error "Invalid retention stage defined.)":

[image]

So everytime you publish a new version of a workflow for a retention policy, be sure to **update your policy action of your document library as well**.

[This great article](http://www.danielroot.info/2012/08/information-management-policy.html) points out the nasty details of recurrence in SharePoint's information policy and helped me to redesign the retention policy from scratch.